# Rails Engine: uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My first question on stack overflow!
I am trying to convert a rails app into an engine so that I can use it in my own Rails app.

I have converted everything to engine modules etc. (I'm still in my engine directory and haven't started implemented it yet in my rails app) but when I run `rake db:migrate` in the root I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant User
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0    /gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0    /gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise.rb:292:in `get'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/mapping.rb:70:in `initialize'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise.rb:326:in `new'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise.rb:326:in `add_mapping'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:238:in `block in devise_for'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `each'
/Users/matthijskolkman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `devise_for'
/Users/matthijskolkman/Projects/customer_service_gem/brimir/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I think it has to do with the routing, but not sure.
Here are my routes:

```
Brimir::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth' }

  resources :users do
    get :tickets, to: 'tickets#index'
  end

  namespace :tickets do
    resource :deleted, only: :destroy, controller: :deleted
    resource :selected, only: :update, controller: :selected
  end

  resources :tickets, except: [:destroy, :edit] do
    resource :lock, only: [:destroy, :create], module: :tickets
  end

  resources :labelings, only: [:destroy, :create]

  resources :rules

  resources :labels, only: [:destroy, :update, :index, :edit]

  resources :replies, only: [:create, :new, :update, :show]

  get '/attachments/:id/:format' => 'attachments#show'
  resources :attachments, only: [:index, :new]

  resources :email_addresses

  resource :settings, only: [:edit, :update]

  root to: 'tickets#index'

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :tickets, only: [ :index, :show, :create ]
      resources :sessions, only: [ :create ]
      resources :users, param: :email, only: [ :create, :show ] do
        resources :tickets, only: [ :index ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the user controller (app/controllers/brimir/users_controller.rb):

```
module Brimir
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include UsersStrongParams
    load_and_authorize_resource :user

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
....
```

Model (app/models/brimir/user.rb)

```
module Brimir
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise Rails.application.config.devise_authentication_strategy, :recoverable,
      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable,
      omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]

    has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :labelings, as: :labelable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :labels, through: :labelings
    has_many :assigned_tickets, class_name: 'Ticket',
        foreign_key: 'assignee_id', dependent: :nullify
    has_many :notifications

    # identities for omniauth
    has_many :identities

    after_initialize :default_localization
    before_validation :generate_password

    # All ldap users are agents by default, remove/comment this method if this
    # is not the intended behavior.
    def ldap_before_save
      self.agent = true
    ....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `User` model defined in your engine or in the main app? It might be worth prefixing with the right module names.

Comment: No thats not the case, because I'm working inside my gem directory and haven't started implementing it yet in my own rails app.

Comment: `devise` is probably looking for the `::User` class. You probably want to tell devise that you are namespacing the `User` class inside `brimir` so that it calls it with `Brimir::User`. Also, since you have your user class inside the folder brimir you should namespace it as-well.